# Regex match all letters after a digit

Tags: regex

I want to match any letters that occur after a digit(s). There will not be any other digits in the sentence.

```
# example 1 one letter
> 'word 1 b'
> array(b)

# example 2 multiple letters
>'3c, d, e'
> array (c, d, e)

# example 3 no match
>'word 5'
> array()

# example 4 multiple letters multiple digits
>'words 12a b c'
> array(a, b, c)
```

I've tried `[^\d]+?([A-Za-z])` but this matches letters before the digits also, and not the one that is attached to the digit (e.g. in example 4, `12a`, or example 2, `3c`)

Comment: With PCRE, `(?:\G(?!^)|\d+)[^a-z]*\K[a-z]`, see https://regex101.com/r/DWH8Jn/1. With the non-fixed-width lookbehind, `(?<=\d.*)[a-z]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/DWH8Jn/2))

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. Feel free to put it as an answer. This wasn't in the original question, but was wondering if there's a way to avoid the word 'and', e.g. `words 12a b and c` we only want `a, b, c` not `a,b,a,n,d,c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [this works for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68986116/regex-match-all-letters-after-a-digit?noredirect=1#comment121922358_68986116), here are the possible solutions:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|\d+)[^a-z]*\K[a-z]
(?<=\d.*)[a-z]
```

See [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/DWH8Jn/1) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/DWH8Jn/2). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\d+)` - one or more digits or the end of the previous successful match
- `[^a-z]*` - any zero or more non-lowercase letters
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase letter.

The second regex means:

- `(?<=\d.*)` -  a location that is immediately preceded with a digit and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase letter.

To exclude the word `and`, you can use

```php
(?:\G(?!^)(?:\s+and\b)?|\d+)[^a-z\n]*\K[a-z]
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DWH8Jn/4). Or,

```js
(?<=\d.*)[a-z](?<!\band\b)(?!(?<=\ban)d\b)(?!(?<=\ba)nd\b)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DWH8Jn/5).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you might need is a *zero-width* group, one that is required by the expression but is not part of the capture. The zero-width lookahead will consume any digits it finds, and the group captured will be anything after the digits.

`(?=d+)(\w+)`